# Use the customiser to set the background-image of a div

Tags: theme-customizer

I am trying to use the customiser to set the background image of each 'post-block' to be that of any image I choose to upload. Here is my code so far.

```
function jhwdblog_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'post_box_image_section' , array(
            'title'      => __( 'Post Box Background', 'jhwdblog' ),
            'description' => 'Upload a logo to replace the post box background image',
            'priority'   => 30,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'post_box_image');

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'post_box_image', array(
            'label'      => __( 'Post Box Image', 'jhwdblog' ),
            'section'    => 'post_box_image_section',
            'settings'   => 'post_box_image',
    )));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'jhwdblog_customize_register' );
```

and in my page i'm trying to add it to the style inline like so

```
<div class="post-block" style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url(get_theme_mod( 'post-box-image' )); ?> ');">
```

However all i get when i check the inspector is background-image: url((unknown)). What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: 
Firstly there is a spelling mistake in that i'm using 'post-box-image' instead of 'post_box_image'...

Secondly it's better to do it this way in functions.php:

```
function jhwd_blog_theme_customize_css()
{
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .post-block { 
            background-image:url('<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'post_box_image' );?>'); 
            background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'post_box_color' );?>;
        }
        .post-block>h1, .post-boxes {
            background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'post_boxes_items_color' );?>;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'jhwd_blog_theme_customize_css');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo in that your `get_theme_mod()` call. You are using `post-box-image` when it should be `post_box_image`. So like this:

```
<div class="post-block" style="background-image:url('<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'post_box_image' ) ); ?>');">
```

Also, when you define your setting you should specify a `sanitize_callback` like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'post_box_image', array(
    'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = esc_url_raw( $value );
            if ( empty( $value ) ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_image' );
            }
        }
        return $value;
    },
) );
```